# Why was my answer down voted, and most importantly why did it not require the user to leave a comment?

Tags: discussion

I am new here and am a little confused. Why are you allowed to down vote an answer without leaving a comment? That provides me with no information as to how to improve my answer.

[Is this safe to download and use Gutenprint driver for Mac from their site?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/266556/is-this-safe-place-to-download/266559#266559)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I didn't and wouldn't downvote your answer, but I could see someone objecting because it makes a rather blanket statement. Basically, you wrote, 'if you want to know if it's safe, ask VirusTotal'; this implies that VirusTotal is 100% accurate, which we know to be impossible in practice. I might have worded it a little differently, such as "if they say it's safe, it's probably safe"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The down vote process asks people to consider leaving constructive criticism, but it isn't required. Sometimes there's nothing significant about a vote other than someone, somehwere on the internet didn't like the post.

or a cat is operating someone's browser and can't figure out how to take the down vote back:

[image: oh noes, what has I done?]

Other times, there's an obvious link to:

A) not enough research shown
B) not enough specificity
C) several questions being asked
D) just not a useful question in one person's eyes

I don't think your answer is nearly as bad as the question. Maybe people felt virus total is spammy?

Comment: A very interesting edit to the original post....  :-)

Comment: Needed more intentional humor, less auto-correst random insertions, @fsb